# Validate an Enum with springframework validation Errors

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, enums, exception

### **TL;DR : Enum deserialization errors are not caught by `org.springframework.validation.Errors` in a Rest Controller**

#### *For reference: we didn't find a clean solution yet as we finally decided that no one should call us wit a bad enum*

---

I have a rest controller that uses `org.springframework.validation.Errors` for parameter validations:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vol1/frodo")
public ResponseEntity<Object> simpleMethodUsingPost(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        @Valid @RequestBody MySimpleObject simpleObject,
        Errors errors) {

    /* If an error occured, I need to log the object */
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        List<FieldError> fields = errors.getFieldErrors();
        doSomething(fields , simpleObject);
    }
}
```

My class `MySimpleObject` looks like this:

```
public class MySimpleObject {
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "anObjectField is a mandatory field")
    private EmbeddedObject anObjectField = null;

    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "aStringField is a mandatory field")
    private String aStringField = null;

    @Valid
    private MySimpleEnum aSimpleEnum = null;
}
```

And my enum class `MySimpleEnum` is basically a class with two values:

```
public enum MySimpleEnum{

  ORC("ORC"),
  URUK("URUK");

  private String value;

  MySimpleEnum(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
  }
}
```

The validation of this object (and the injection of errors in the springframework `Error` object) works well when it's on a `String` or an `Object`, but it will fail validation of an `enum` (hence an object containing a valid-annoted enum will fail too).

It fails when trying to cast the JSON `String` to an enum when the value is not valid:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: 
Cannot deserialize value of type 'lotr.middleearth.model.MySimpleEnum' from String "HOBBIT"
```

This deserialization error is caught if I use a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and override `handleHttpMessageNotReadable`, but then I don't have access to the different other parameters and can't use them.

How can I configure either a **Validator**, **enum** or **springframework Error** so that this exception is caught and usable in my controller body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across the same problem but didn't like the idea of giving the user an unformatted "ugly" validation error message.

First, I made the enum property not nullable on the pojo.

```
@NotNull(message = "Type must be NEW_APPLICATION or RENEWAL")
private RegistrationSubmissionTypeEnum type;
```

Then I changed the setter to basically check the input (as a string) and see if it matches one of the enums.  If not, I do nothing, the property stays null and it's reported back as one of the validation error messages (using the message text used on the @NotNull annotation).

```
public void setType(Object typeInput) {
    for (RegistrationSubmissionTypeEnum typeEnum : RegistrationSubmissionTypeEnum.values()) {
        if (typeEnum.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(typeInput.toString())) {
            this.type=RegistrationSubmissionTypeEnum.valueOf(typeInput.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

That's really the key.  The normal behavior we all despise generates an ugly error message, but it also does it in a way such that this error message is displayed alone.  Personally, I like to send back all errors en masse.

I'm not a fan of hardcoding the enum values on the @NotNull message, but in this particular case (small number of enum values), it's preferable to the default enum serialization error message, and the behavior of a one-off isolated error message.

I considered a custom validator, but that started to feel heavy.  Maybe someone can improve on this.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks! I'll try that as soon as i can

Answer (score 0):

The problem that is occurring is that in the enum MySimpleEnum there is no constant "HOBBIT" the possibilities are "ORC" and "URUK", in the validation question can be used simply as in the example:

```
@NotNull(message = "Custom message")
private MySimpleEnum aSimpleEnum
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that there is no constant Hobbit in my enum, that's why it's an error case; I will try to replace the @ Valid with @ NotNull but I think it'll trigger a jsonparse exception anyway (it gets triggered before the validation)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like that to extract the problematic field in the request :

```
int start = ex.getMessage().indexOf("[\"");
int end = ex.getMessage().indexOf("\"]");
String fieldName = exception.getMessage().substring(start + 2, end)
```

The field happens to be at the end of the message between the brackets.

I'm not really proud of that one, it's messy, but it seems to be the only way with enums.

I guess it would be better to use strings and proper Spring validation instead, since it depends too much on the implementation and may break with future updates.